# need to select the data that does not exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exists

There are 2 tables. Table one has an id which has multiple entries in table 2. I need to select an id which doesn't have a particular record (in those multiple records in table 2 only one row shouldn't be present). Please tell me how to do this.

Eg:

```
Table 1       Table 2
A             A 2
B             A 3
C             B 2
              B 3
              C 3
```

Now I need to select the rows from table 1 that are not associated with rows containing value `2` in table 2. (i.e. C should be selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
select t1.*
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1)
where t2.col2 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sql excludes rows from table1 where the corresponding row in table 2 has a column with value 2 (the value you want to exclude)

```
SELECT t1.col1
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.col2  From Table2 t2 WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 =2)
```